# Surface integral applying Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

I want to calculate the surface integral

$$\iint_{\partial S}\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\right)\cdot\mathbf{n}\,\mathrm{d}A,$$

when

$$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = {y\,z\,{\bf i}-x\,z\,{\bf j}+\left(x^2-y^2\right)\,z\,{\bf k}}$$

and

$$S = \left\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+(z-{2})^2\le{25},\,0\le z\le{2} \right\}.$$

So the z-component of the surface normal n is positive everywhere.

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=(x-2zy)\mathbf i +(y-2xz)\mathbf j + (-2z)\mathbf k$$

We can see that $r^2=25\to r=5$

But how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Have you learnt about [the Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) a.k.a. Gauss' Theorem?

Comment: The $z$-component of the unit normal isn't positive everywhere is it?  $S$ is the slice of sphere of radius $5$ centered at $(,0,2)$ between the $z=0$ and $z=2$ planes.  On the bottom of this slice, the outward normal is $-\mathbf{k}$.  But the divergence theorem is the way to go as @md2perpe indicated.

Comment: Also, do you know what is the divergence of a rotation, $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{F})$?